# Renaming columns not containing specific suffix

Tags: r, grepl

I want to rename columns in dataframe 'SOURCE_SUBSET' not contain the substring "_dich" with the suffix '_dich' and all other columns to have the original name.

exmaple:
GGADA202_dich should remain the same
GGADA203 should become GGADA203_dich

This is what I have so far. It is not working correctly: GGADA202_dich becomes GGADA202_dich_dich_dich

```
ifelse(grepl("_dich", colnames(SOURCE_SUBSET), fixed=TRUE),
       colnames(SOURCE_SUBSET) <- paste(colnames(SOURCE_SUBSET), "dich", sep = "_"),colnames(SOURCE_SUBSET))
```

Comment: Try `colnames(SOURCE_SUBSET) <- sub("^(?!.*_dich)(.*)", "\\1_dich", colnames(SOURCE_SUBSET), perl=TRUE)`

Comment: it renames all with the suffix...

Comment: The `"^(?!.*_dich)(.*)"` pattern matches strings that do not contain `_dich`. Make sure you use `perl=TRUE`. Those that do not match remain as is. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/3PjzjA).

Comment: See https://ideone.com/3PjzjA

Comment: Thank you Wiktor!

Comment: If you need to only add `_dich` if it is not at the end, use `"colnames(SOURCE_SUBSET) <- sub("$(?<!_dich)", "_dich", colnames(SOURCE_SUBSET), perl=TRUE)"`

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
colnames(SOURCE_SUBSET) <- sub("^(?!.*_dich)(.*)", "\\1_dich", colnames(SOURCE_SUBSET), perl=TRUE)
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/3PjzjA) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zof3T9/1).

The `^(?!.*_dich)(.*)` pattern matches strings that do not contain `_dich`. Make sure you use `perl=TRUE` as lookaheads are not supported by the default TRE library. Those names that do not match will remain as is.

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*_dich)` - no `_dich` is allowed after any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible from the start of the string
- `(.*)` - grabs into Group 1 (this text is inserted back into the result using `'\\1'` in the replacement pattern) any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

Answer (score 1):

tidyverse approach

```
library( tidyverse )
#if a column name does not contain the string"_dich", add the suffix "_dich"
df %>% rename_at( vars( -contains( "_dich" ) ), funs( paste0(., "_dich") ) )
```